# Jquery Mobile - How do I show a loading image until all the images on the page are loaded?

Tags: image, jquery-mobile

I have a webpage - it has a background image.

I only want the page to show when the image has done loading.

I can see that jquery mobile has a "loader" gif, but I cannot work out how to show the loader gif up to and until the image has finished loading.

If the page looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="a">
    ... the rest of the page
    </div>
</body></html>
```

and the class "a" is defined as this

.a {
    background-image: url("/WebContent/img/someImageHere.jpg");
    background-position: 70% 40%;
}

What would show the loader image (and only the loader image) when the page opens, up to and until the image someImageHere.jpg is finished loading?

Comment: are you using jQM as a framework? or you want to use its' loader widget?

Comment: i have the jqm js file (and the general jq) loaded on my webpage. i'm not using jqm as a framework per say, it just helped with things like making checkboxes look pretty, and stopped the page blowing up in mobile devices when an input field was selected.

Comment: You cant bind any event to CSS background images. you can instead load background img in hidden div in DOM and then update your target div's `background-image` property. http://jsfiddle.net/p7xj8d2d/2/